# How do i set PHP work in strict mode?

Tags: php

Today i make a ridiculous mistake,and i use half day to find this out.

the code below:

```
$conn = db_connect ( DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME );
$sql = "SELECT u.*, c.name FROM ost_user u, ost_company c WHERE u.id='" . $id . "' AND c.id=u.companyid;";
$query = db_query( $sql, DBNAME, $conn);
if (mysql_num_rows ( $query ) != 1) {
    die ( "User not found!" );
}
else
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $_SESSION['username'] == $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['companyid'] == $row['companyid'];
}
```

So the problem is significant,

```
$_SESSION['username'] == $row['username'];
$_SESSION['companyid'] == $row['companyid'];
```

So both session keep NULL on going.

I set the php.ini error level to E_ALL, but it doesn't raise any warning message, but it should not happen on .NET/Java platform.

So is it any setting i can make on php.ini or somewhere i can enforce the value should have asignment?

Comment: This *`mysql_num_rows`* is the ridiculous mistake, consider using `mysqli_()` or `PDO` instead

Comment: `$x == $y` is not incorrect, it's valid expression.

Comment: this is just an honest user error. no amount of error/warning reporting will help you, since that is valid syntax.

Comment: `$_SESSION['username'] == $row['username'];` ??

Comment: Did you `session_start()` ?

Comment: If you use an IDE like phpstorm it will highlight issues like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get any syntax error here and the values won't be assigned if you use double equals `==`. Take this example

```
<?php

$car ='car';
$book ='book';
$car == $book;

echo $car; // Prints car , not book.
?>
```

Some popular IDE's will show you this when you use that operator.

> Expression is calculated but the calculation result is not used
>   anywhere. This may be caused by a misspelling when the ‘=’ operator is
>   replaced with ‘==’ by mistake.

Also ,add this to your PHP code (Not neccessary in your case though)

```
error_reporting(E_STRICT);
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression you highlighted is perfectly valid:

```
$_SESSION['username'] == $row['username'];
$_SESSION['companyid'] == $row['companyid'];
```

If you had done something like this:

```
$_SESSION['username'] == $row['username'];
$_SESSION['companyid'] p== $row['companyid'];
```

Then you would get an error because it is not valid code.

The compiler can only verify if your code is valid or not. It is not aware of your intentions and as such can't determine if the code is going to do what you *intend* it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try php's Error reporting set to 1:

http://php.about.com/od/troubleshooting/qt/php_error_reporting.htm

```
error_reporting(1);
```